# How to work out the formula that connects several numbers

Tags: data-analysis

I have an interesting problem. Say I have lots of datasets like this:

```
a = 21
b = 23
c = 58
d = 498
etc (lots of other values)

X = 85
```

I need to find the formula that derives X from a, b, c, d etc, with the added complication that I don't know whether all of the values affect X or whether some have no effect on it. Is there a generic method to do that?

I do not have the ability to vary a, b, c and d and check the derived value of X; however, I have a huge amount of these datasets (combinations of values and the resulting X) to look at. I have some programming skills, so I am able to analyse all of these datasets using an algorithm, but I have literally no idea what that algorithm should be. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I am new to this site, and don't know which tags to use, so feel free to retag this.

EDIT: Each dataset contains the same amount of numbers, and the positions are fixed, i.e. 'a' of one dataset corresponds to the 'a' in others.

Comment: In general, for a finite sequence of numbers there is no way to tell which one should be 'next', i.e. to tell what $X$ should be. Is there any additional structure to how $X$ relates to $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, etc?

Comment: I have a general idea for which of a, b, c, d et al are related to X, but I'm not sure. But surely, with the huge volume of data that I have, I should be able to find a relationship?

Comment: Entering $1+1$ into your calculator and pressing enter, it will respond $2$ a million times over. But there's no way to be sure (mathematically) that it will *always* do so unless you know something about the inner workings of your calculator. You will need to know (or assume) *something* about how the output relates to the input if you want to find a relationship mathematically.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I've probably misunderstood you, but I can assume that the calculator I have here is *consistent*, that is, if a, b, c, d etc are the same, then X will *always* be the same.

Comment: I admit I was a bit vague. I am indeed assuming that your process is consistent.

What you are asking for is an algorithm that, given an arbitrary sequence of numbers, outputs *the* next number in the sequence. But there is no way to determine what *the* next number should be. In fact, a sequence is defined by giving *all* of its terms, so *any* number could be next.

Comment: Unless you have some restrictions, i.e. some relations, which your sequence should satisfy.

Comment: Relations... like what? Maximum values? The maximum value of any parameter (a, b, c, d, etc or X) is 99. Anything else?

Comment: This certainly narrows things down, but it is not sufficient to determine $X$ from this. What *would* be sufficient precisely is a difficult question. An example of a relation would be: "If $a$ is doubled, then so is $X$", or "$X$ is less than the sum of all the inputs". Do you have any relation like this between input and output?

Comment: Right, I think I understand now. I have an assumption that I'm not sure is true, but I guess I will have to stick with it. The assumption is that X is a weighted average of all the other data, so a might have half the weight of b, twice that of c, and d might have no weight at all.

Comment: Then it remains to determine the weights of each of the variables. For this you need at least as many data sets as you have variables. However if you have more, then there might be no solution (meaning your assumption might be false).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14848/discussion-between-bluefire-and-servaes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think there is a linear relationship between the $a, b, c$, *etc.*, and $x$, then you could find the least-squares solution to the system of equations $\mathbf {Ay = X}$. The matrix $\mathbf A$ will consist of rows of the form $[a_i\ b_i\ c_i \ldots]$, and $\mathbf X$ is a column vector containing the values $x_i$. The vector $\mathbf y$ corresponds to the weights in your weighted average.

The system $\mathbf {Ay = X}$ does not necessarily have a solution, but you can find the "best fit" by multiplying both sides by $\mathbf A^t$ and solving the resulting system; *i.e.*, $\mathbf {A}^t\mathbf{Ay} = \mathbf{A}^t\mathbf{X}$.

Thus the best-fit solution for your weights is $\mathbf{\hat y} = (\mathbf{A}^t\mathbf{A})^{-1}\mathbf{A}^t\mathbf{X}$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbf A^t$?

Comment: I mean the transpose of the matrix $\mathbf A$.

Comment: I'm not too experienced with matrices and linear algebra, so I don't know what that is D: Is software like Matlab able to process this for me?

Comment: Yes, Matlab would certainly be able to do this. In fact, it is such a common problem that, from what I see, the syntax in Matlab is as simple as "$\mathtt{y = A\backslash X}$". Here's a link to the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html). Note that the variables on that page are slightly different from here; they're solving the system $\mathbf{Ax = B}$, so you'll have to relabel accordingly.